# Does this query always correctly retrieve the types of array parameters

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

The following query seems to work, but I am not sure that it is the best/always correct way:

```
select 
parameter_name, 
CASE WHEN data_type='ARRAY' 
    THEN SUBSTRING(udt_name, 2)||'[]' 
    ELSE data_type 
END AS data_type
from information_schema.parameters 
where specific_schema='my_schema'
and parameter_mode='IN'
and specific_name like 'my_proc_16831'
order by ordinal_position
```

Anyway, it looks kind of hacky to me. Is there a better way to retrieve, for example, numeric[] as a type if my parameter is an array of numeric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `format_type(typid oid, typmod integer)`.

Given:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;

CREATE FUNCTION my_schema.my_proc_16831(numeric[])
RETURNS numeric[] LANGUAGE sql AS $$
SELECT $1;
$$;
```

You can get proc details with:

```
SELECT
  p.parameter_name,
  format_type((p.udt_schema||'.'||p.udt_name)::regtype, -1) 
FROM information_schema.parameters AS p
INNER JOIN information_schema.routines 
  USING (specific_catalog, specific_schema, specific_name) 
WHERE specific_schema = 'my_schema'   
  AND parameter_mode = 'IN'
  AND routine_name = 'my_proc_16831';
```

... though this removes the portability of using `information_schema`, since you're relying on Pg specific behaviour. It also assumes the typmod is always -1 because PostgreSQL doesn't keep track of the typmod for functions - e.g. `numeric(18,2)` becomes just `numeric` as a function argument.

At least this way you don't need to use your `LIKE` hack, though, or relying on changeable assumptions about array internal type names.

BTW, you can use `pg_proc` and `pg_type` directly instead. This might be worth doing if performance is critical, though otherwise `information_schema` will be more cross-version portable.

That gives you the equivalent:

```
SELECT 
  proargnames[argpos] AS arg_name, 
  format_type(proargtypes[argpos],-1) AS arg_type 
FROM pg_proc p 
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (p.pronamespace = n.oid) 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_subscripts(proargtypes, 1) argpos
WHERE n.nspname = 'my_schema'
  AND p.proname = 'my_proc_16831' 
/* AK: suggested additional clause
      AND argpos > 0
*/
    ORDER BY p.proname, argpos;
```

Comment: Craig, your first query works for me. Your second one returns one extra row with empty arg_name and argpos=0. What does that row mean?

Comment: Also I added AND parameter_mode = 'IN', so that it works for functions which return data.